# PhoneGap, ChildBrowser, & Printing

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cordova, phonegap-plugins

OK, first the basics, I'm running cordova 1.5.0 (PhoneGap) with the latest version of ChildBrowser from the phonegap-plugins (the one compatible with cordova 1.5), Xcode 4.3.1 and iOS 5.1. Now the problem. I have code that works everywhere including a really basic test app to display and show an iOS Print panel. That is it works everywhere EXCEPT in PhoneGap. For the life of me, I can't get it to work. I assume it has something to do with the View Hierarchy created by PhoneGap and a PhoneGap Plugin.

In ChildBrowserViewController.h I added this:

```
- (IBAction)sendPrint:(id)sender;
```

And then wired this up to a button labeled Print (I know, I should use the system action button, for the sake of this problem I'm just trying to get it working). In ChildBrowserViewController.m I added the following implementation:

```
- (IBAction)sendPrint:(id)sender
{
    UIPrintInteractionController *printController = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
    UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
    printController.printInfo = printInfo;

    printController.printFormatter = [self.webView viewPrintFormatter];

    void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) =
    ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error)
    {};

    [printController presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
}
```

Note that this implementation is stripped down of all error checking for posting here, this is the minimal implementation that still works outside of PhoneGap.

I have been pulling my hair out for the last couple of days trying to get this to work to no avail. So I'm hopeful someone else has some idea, and given the number of people I've seen who want to add print to ChildBrowser, if I can provide a starting point,all the better.

BTW, it dies in objc_msgSend with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2,address=0x0). And I tried enabling Zombies with no additional help there either.

Thanks so much for any help.

Andrew

Comment: OK, its not solved yet but I have more information. It also seems to fail using a UIDocumentInteractionController where again you have no control over the context in which its run, but I have an MFMailComposeViewController running just fine (which you call on self). So it definitely seems to be the view hierarchy that is screwed up (or at least not what the controllers that I don't have control over are expecting). Still struggling, only now with two issues since I need a UIDocumentInteractionController as well as the UIPrintInteractionController. My guess is solving one will solve them both.

Comment: Solved the problem with UIDocumentInteractionController, but using the same pattern didn't solve the problem with UIPrintInteractionController. In case you're wondering, I solved the problem with UIDocumentInteractionController by integrating the code outlined [here](https://github.com/ebzlo/phonegap-plugins/commit/d7514e6bf3e9889ea8b41d1103d0772a0e15e5f4). Now back to beating my head against a brick wall.

Comment: I am not sure its fully solved yet (OK, I know its NOT fully solved yet). It WORKS on my device, it FAILS on the simulator. It was failing on the device last time a tried (which admittedly was yesterday). Now I wish I could understand why the simulator is failing, yet on the device its working. Grrrrr, head getting very very sore at the moment. Brick wall not crumbling yet. Should I be happy it at least changed its position?

Comment: Additional progress. I have it running in the Simulator now by adding  `if(self){}` to the completion routine. It really seems to me like something bad is going on in memory if simply referencing an external variable in the code block allows Printing in the simulator to work. Now I have a new problem. The Print button only works once before causing the ChildBrowser to unload and requiring restarting the App to continue. Also on the iPad, I get the iPhone behavior despite using `[printController presentFromBarButtonItem:sender animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler]`.